# Update image visualization parameters from slider UI elements in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2, animation

I'm trying to change the visualization parameters (`min` and `max`) of NDVI images in an Earth Engine App with slider controls. The result is an animation of styled images.

The animation part works well, but in order to see the variance in the images, the user must be able to change the `min` and `max` according to their region of interest with a slider.

My attempt to update image styling is on line 46, but it does not work as intended. Here's the code:

```
Map.setCenter(-102.24954, 36.10286, 14); 

var palette1 = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', 
'99B718', '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401',
'056201', '004C00','023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
var min1 = 0.2;
var max1 = 0.8;
var images = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
    .filterDate('2018-01-01','2030-12-31')
    .sort('system:time_start', false)
    .filterBounds(Map.getCenter());
var visNDVI = {min: min1, max: max1, palette: palette1};    
var ndvi = images.map(function(image) {
  var result = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename("ndvi");
  return image.addBands(result);});
var imagesNDVI = ee.ImageCollection(ndvi).select('ndvi').limit(8);
var animation = require('users/gena/packages:animation');

var label = ui.Label('Set Min NDVI Value');
var slider = ui.Slider({
  min: 0, max: 1, step: 0.05, value: 0.3,
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal', width:'300px'},
  onChange: updateLayer
});

var label1 = ui.Label('Set Max NDVI Value');
var slider1 = ui.Slider({
  min: 0, max: 1, step: 0.05, value: 0.7,
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal', width:'300px'},
  onChange: updateLayer
});

var panel = ui.Panel({
      widgets: [label, slider, label1, slider1],
      layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical'),
      style: {position: 'top-right',width: '295px'
      }
    });
Map.add(panel);

function updateLayer(value){
  var min1 = slider.getValue();
  var max1 = slider1.getValue();
  Map.layers().reset();
  var desired =     imagesNDVI.updateMask(imagesNDVI.get(visNDVI).get(min).set(min1).get(max).set(max1));
  Map.addLayer(desired, {palette: palette1});    
}

animation.animate(imagesNDVI, {maxFrames: 50, vis: visNDVI, timeStep: 500});
```

[Link to my GEE script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fc634695c16f0a05a668ea4a137c4728)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateLayer` function should look like this:

```js
function updateLayer(value){
  // Get min stretch value from user.
  var min1 = slider.getValue();
  // Get max stretch value from user.
  var max1 = slider1.getValue();
  // Set a new visualization definition based on user min and max.
  var visNDVInew = {min: min1, max: max1, palette: palette1};
  // Remove all the current animation layers
  Map.layers().reset();
  // Remove the current animation panel.
  Map.remove(Map.widgets().get(1));
  // Reanimate the collection to apply the visualization changes.
  animation.animate(imagesNDVI, {maxFrames: 50, vis: visNDVInew, timeStep: 500});
}
```

You need to set `min1` and `max1` as properties of `min` and `max` in a visualization definition dictionary and then remove the old animation and then re-animate the collection with the new visualization definition.

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/15a13a2c3408d9ffc2c2d6de5b7bb817)

Comment: Thank you very much
This have been a great help for me